# Difference-in-differences with monthly data where the previous untreated year is used as the control group

Tags: regression, panel-data, difference-in-difference, economics

I recently came across a setup of differences-in-differences which I have previously wondered about, but had not seen before in a published study. Consider the following setting:

Outcome: measured at the monthly level (e.g., employment rate) across multiple units (e.g., states). Data is available across multiple years.

Treatment: policy that impacted all the units in year T' after month t' (e.g., the pandemic in march 2020).

Diff-in-diff design: we will use the monthly outcome data in years before T' as a control group. That is we assume in the absence of the intervention, the monthly outcome data follows the same trend in year T' as say the previous year. So our DD estimate will be the pre- and post- monthly outcome change in year T' relative to say the previous year T'-1 where the policy was never introduced.

So far I have found two papers published in economic journals that have used this approach:

1. Metcalfe et al. (2011, The Economic Journal) to study the impact of the 9/11 attacks on subjective well-being.
2. Brodeur et al. (2021, Journal of Public Economics) to study the impacts of COVID-19 stay-at-home mandate on mental health outcomes.

My question is simply whether this type of difference-in-difference design is well known, or if it has a special name. It differs from the conventional design which leverages variation in treatment status across units post-treatment. I found this Stata list post where someone wanted to use this type of design but was being criticized as being wrong by multiple active stata list posters:

https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1651271-difference-in-differences-and-panel-data

The design introduced above personally seems intuitive to me. But I wasn't sure if there is some well known criticism against this type of design? I don't recall ever seeing it an econometrics textbook.

Comment: It sounds like you describing an event study design.

Comment: @dimitriy Sure it can be an event study design, but even there traditionally we use variation in treatment status across units post-treatment. Here, everyone gets treated, but since we have monthly data, we can attempt to use the trends from the previous year to construct the counterfactual in the treated year.

Comment: Perhaps there are terminology differences across fields, but you don't need variation in treatment post-treatment for an event study. Here is [a practical description](https://theeffectbook.net/ch-EventStudies.html) of this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the response @dimitriy. That link is helpful. In economics an event study is usually when units become treated at different points in time. In most cases these is also a group that never receives the treatment in these contexts as well. But as that link suggests, an event study can be just before vs. after.